# Regex to extract selective lines

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a list of error messages:

```
def errorMessages = ["Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported"
                     "Line : 2 Could not parse INVOICE_DATE value"
                     "Line 3 : Could not parse ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT value"
                     "Line 4 : MATH ERROR"
                     "cl_id is a required field"
                     "File Error : The file does not contain delimiters"
                     "lf_name is a required field"]
```

I am trying to create a new list which doesn't match the `regex "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+"` but has the text `Invoice does not foot Reported`.

My desired new list should be like this:

```
def headErrors= ["Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported"
                 "cl_id is a required field"
                 "File Error : The file does not contain delimiters"
                 "lf_name is a required field"]
```

This is what I am doing for now:

```
regex = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+"
errorMessages.each{
    if(it.contains('Invoice does not foot Reported'))
        headErrors.add(it)
    else if(!it.matches(regex)
        headErrors.add(it)
}
```

Is there a way it can be done just using regex instead of `if` `else`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `findAll()` instead of `each()`. `findAll()` is a filter function which can be used on a Collection/Iterable or Map. It filters the result on satisfying the condition provided by the `Closure` parameter.

Here, you can filter `String` which has the desired `text` or does not match with the supplied regex. Using `findAll` is better than `each` because it returns the filtered collection as a result as compared to each which returns the Collection itself.

```
def regex = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+"

def headErrors = errorMessages.findAll { 
    it.contains('Invoice does not foot Reported') || !(it ==~ regex) 
}

assert headErrors ==  [
    'Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported', 
    'cl_id is a required field', 
    'File Error : The file does not contain delimiters', 
    'lf_name is a required field'
]
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498625/create-a-new-map-string-liststring-with-selective-elements-from-another-map